# Revolution slider video autoplay not working

Tags: video, slider, autoplay

I have a problem with autoplay in chrome.

http://grouptelcom.com/

```
    <!-- BACKGROUND VIDEO LAYER-->
    <div class="rs-background-video-layer" 
        data-forcerewind="on" 
        data-volume="mute" 
        data-videowidth="100%" 
        data-videoheight="100%" 
        data-videomp4="http://grouptelcom.com/assets/videos/video.mp4" 
        data-videopreload="auto" 
        data-forceCover="1" 
        data-aspectratio="16:9" 
        data-autoplay="true" 
        data-videoloop="loopandnoslidestop"
        data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false" 
        ></div>
```

I wrote all parameters on option what need to autoplay, but if i go to site first time autoplay didnt work.

Chrome console had error>

```
revolution.extension.video.js:1320 Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before.
```

Comment: Any luck solved that? I have same problem in 2018

Comment: I see you have solved this on your site.  We're having the same problem on our site with autoplay not starting unless the user interacts with the document.  What was your solution?

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED Revolution slider not autoplay youtube chrome 2019**

**Step =  1 copy below css**

```
   .rs-background-video-layer iframe {
    visibility:inherit !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    }
```

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step 3**

[image]

**OTHER WISE PASTE BELOW JAVASCRIPT Add this in Slider Settings > Custom JavaScript (Slider Revolution Video Autoplay)**

```
revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onvideostop",function (e,data) { 
     var player = data.video; 
     player.play(); 
 });
```

Comment: fixed it in google chrome...safari on iphone and chrome on android not working though.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest version (5.4.8.2 at time of post), along with following all guidelines highlighted [here](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/video-audio-changes-safari-chrome/) fixed this issue for me.  I tried other solutions with modifying the plugin, or adding javascript as a patch but nothing is as reliable as just taking the update from the plugin creator :)